# for loop * line java

Tags: java, for-loop, java.util.scanner

I need to ask for a number to be input and the output will be a line of `*` to the value of the input `num`. I am going wrong somewhere, I have asked for the input and made it int j but when I do my for loop I am getting errors.

Please know I am not looking for the direct answer but if someone could please point me in the right direction that would be awesome. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question48 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //Declaring and naming the scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Declaring the variables needed for the class
        int j;

        //Prompt
        System.out.print("Enter a number here between 1 & 10: ");
        j = input.nextInt();

        if(int k = 0; k <= j; k++)
        {
            System.out.println("* ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: put for instead of if in the last part of code

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic java syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you, change this

```
if(int k = 0; k <= j; k++)
{
  System.out.println("* ");
}
```

to

```
for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
{
  System.out.print("*");
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: Thanks a million for getting back to me. @Elliot Frisch

Answer (score 3):

```
 if(int k = 0; k <= j; k++)
    {
        System.out.println("* ");
    }
```

should be

```
for(int k = 0; k <= j; k++)
    {
        System.out.println("* ");
    }
```

The code you used wouldn't even run since **if** syntax is violated.